# MySQL filter based on inner join

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: ProductOrder and ProductOrderStatusHistory.

Each ProductOrder record has many status histories.

Each ProductOrderStatusHistory record has a status and a product order associated with.

I'm looping through product orders and I want to ignore any orders that have a certain status assigned to it. Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT po.id FROM product_order as po
INNER JOIN product_order_status_history posh ON posh.product_order = po.id
AND posh.order_status <> 5
```

My problem is I don't know how to filter out the entire product order when I encounter a specific status.

For example:

```
 po     | posh status
--------+------------
 126024 | 11
 126024 | 5
 140582 | 6
 140582 | 10
```

If the status I want to ignore is 5, then product order 126024 would not be included in the query result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `NOT EXIST` clause:

```
SELECT po.id FROM product_order as po
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT 0 FROM product_order_status_history posh 
  WHERE posh.product_order = po.id
    AND posh.order_status = 5
)
```

Below is a version that joins two tables, but skips the whole product:

```
SELECT po.id FROM product_order as po
INNER JOIN product_order_status_history posh ON posh.product_order = po.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
      SELECT 0 FROM product_order_status_history posh1 
      WHERE posh1.product_order = po.id
        AND posh1.order_status = 5
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the status condition to the queries WHERE part like

`SELECT po.id FROM product_order as po
INNER JOIN product_order_status_history posh ON posh.product_order = po.id WHERE posh.order_status <> 5`

This should filter your query result by the joined tables property.

Comment: This doesn't work. All it gives me is a duplicate product order record for every status that isn't 5. That is what is frustrating me, it's like the comparison needs to happen inside the join, or inside of a subquery. Just can't figure it out.